# Is this movement through other trucks in Auf Achse correct?

Tags: auf-achse

*I've the 1987 edition of Auf Achse. Would be interested in an answer for that and if it's any different in the 2007 version.*

When moving past other trucks, the rules translation we have (from the [Games Cabinet](http://www.gamecabinet.com/rules/AufAchse.html), a pre BGG resource) uses the word 'miss' for the occupied space, so we treat the occupied space as if it does not exist.  However, I'm not that confident of the translation given a number of other errors.

We play that a roll of `3` results in:

```
-- Started here -- Empty space -- Another Truck here -- Empty space -- Ended up here --
```

Is this correct?

Comment: Fine with leaving this title edit, since it is in context, but note that this is not necessary for search engine optimisation. *Stack Overflow is optimized so that tags are indexed by search engines along with the content of the question.* See [Should questions include tags in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles)

Comment: @ire_and_curses Ok, useful info, ta.  As a _human_ browser I actively prefer the game name somewhere in the title of others' questions, so that was also part of the motivation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2007 rule book PDF I have says "It is permitted to drive through spaces with trucks." Unfortunately, I don't know where I got the PDF so I don't know if it's an official translation. It has the 2007 Schmidt Spiele artwork though, so could be.

The SpotLight on Games rules translation from 2003 (and thus presumably for the 1987 edition) ([here](http://spotlightongames.com/rules/aufachse.html)) says "However, it is allowed to pass another player's truck in either direction."

Neither says anything about skipping the space though. I've always played it as the occupied space counts but you may not be able to stop on it. (In 1987 rules, you can't stop on it if there's a truck there. In 2007 rules, 2 trucks can occupy a highway space. You can still pass them even if the space is "full" though, so long as you end on a legal space.)

Comment: Great link - thanks. That translation looks like a variant (i.e. clarified revision) of the translation I have (from the Game Cabinet), but the phrasing of some critical sentences is subtly different.